# ternary operator in spring configuration file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, maven-3, spring-el

I have a situation where I need to check the profile maven is running on and then according to that I need to configure task scheduler. There are two profiles one is 'global' and the other one is 'nonglobal', what I did is:

```
<task:scheduler id="customerPortalTaskScheduler" pool-size="1" />
    <task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="customerPortalTaskScheduler">
        <task:scheduled ref="SubscriptionService" method="updateNextDistributionDateForAllCurrentUsers" cron="${nhst.ncp.instance} == 'global' ? #{customerportal['globalUpdateDistributionDateServiceTuesday.CronTrigger']} : #{customerportal['updateDistributionDateServiceMondayThursday.CronTrigger']}" />
        <task:scheduled ref="SubscriptionService" method="updateNextDistributionDateForAllCurrentUsers" cron="${nhst.ncp.instance} == 'global' ? #{customerportal['globalUpdateDistributionDateServiceWednesday.CronTrigger']} : #{customerportal['updateDistributionDateServiceFriday.CronTrigger']}" />
        <task:scheduled ref="SubscriptionService" method="updateNextDistributionDateForAllCurrentUsers" cron="${nhst.ncp.instance} == 'global' ? #{customerportal['globalUpdateDistributionDateServiceThursday.CronTrigger']} : #{customerportal['updateDistributionDateServiceWeekend.CronTrigger']}" />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>
```

${nhst.ncp.instance} is instance of maven profile. It would say whether its global or nonglobal profile. It does work fine, because properties file are being loaded properly.

With the above configuration, I am getting an error which is there in screenshot.[image]

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I can't see the screenshot well, low resolution. Please copy paste.

Comment: Do the different profiles run on different machines (possibility to different configurations?)

Comment: Cron has a different meaning for `?` It doesn't support Java syntax.

Comment: Screenshot is fine if you right click and select show image.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I know that it was misinterpreted by java, but what could be the solution then?

Comment: @Gunslinger yes its different configurations.

Comment: I guess you have a good reason to not load the apropriate value from an external config file?

Comment: @Gunslinger you are probably right, but is there any other workaround? And would task-scheduler still work?

Comment: Makes you almost wish you could program in Java instead of having to program in XML. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not depend on profile activated. Depend on local configuration file:

```
<context:property-placeholder ignore-resource-not-found="true" location="file:/etc/mumbojumbo/app.config.properties"/>
```

in /etc/mumbojumbo/app.config.properties

```
cron.schedule = blabla
```

You can always provide a sensible default value. So you only have to override it where you want.

```
<task:scheduled ref="SubscriptionService" method="updateNextDistributionDateForAllCurrentUsers" cron="${cron.schedule:defaultvalue}" />
```

Something like that?

Comment: ya well, if not other choice then I have to do as you said. :) Thanks.